# One to one Entity Framework Relations

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

We need one-to-one relations, do we need to define the relation inside both of the classes which are connected?
Let's say we need an one-to-one relation between Ticket and Project; do we need to add

```
public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
```

and add the same come (Ticket instead of Project) to the ticket class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! You are supposed to add it in both the classes. There are 2 ways of creating one-to-one relation.

1. Using data annotations
2. Using Fluent API

Please refer this below URL. It is well explained with example.
https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx